# Electron -- requiring module in Chromium script

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, electron, requires

I'm trying to work on an Electron app and have been having a problem with trying to require a module from another script running within the Chromium browser window.  No matter what I do to specify the relative path, I'm always coming across the same error about being unable to find a module.

My project is set up like this:

```
    index.html
    scripts
        controllers
            controller.js
        models
            game.js
        tests
            spec
                gameSpec.js
```

My index.html, which is the page brought up by default when electron launches, loads controller.js as a normal script at the end of the body tag.

```
<script src="scripts/controllers/controller.js"></script>
```

controller.js has the following code at the top:

```
var Game = require("../models/game.js");
.... some other code .....
var game = new Game();
```

Upon launching the electron Chromium window, I instantly run into this problem:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../models/game.js'
```

My assumption is that I need a relative path from the controller.js file to the game.js file that it is importing, but no matter what kind of tweaking I do I'm always getting that error.  I don't think it's a mere syntax error since I have the spec under the tests folder all running and passing which successfully uses a require like this:

```
var Game = require("../../models/game.js");
describe("Game", function () { ... });
```

Am I making an incorrect assumption about how require relative pathing is done when executed from the Chromium browser?  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps more of a workaround than an answer, but if you swap your script inclusion from this:

```
<script src="scripts/controllers/controller.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script>require('./scripts/controllers/controller.js')</script>
```

Then the relative paths should work as you are expecting.

---

I *think* that when you include scripts with the `src` attribute, then the internal context of the current working directory in that file is the root of the application.

Why? I'm not 100% sure, to be honest. Limitation on how the files have to be loaded when included as script `src`? If you *really* want to continue using the `src` attribute, these would technically work in `controller.js`.

```
var Game = require(__dirname + '/scripts/models/game.js');
// or
var Game = require('./scripts/models/game.js');
```

I can't whole-heartedly suggest either of those options, though. Seems fragile.

To be honest, I've never even noticed this before, because I typically include a javascript "entry" point to my application in the same location as my `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  Unfortunately the <script>require(....)</script> didn't work, resulting in the same error.   Luckily your suggestion for var Game = require(__dirname....) works like a charm, though I agree it looks fragile and leaves me concerned about what will happen when I want to package the app.  I'm converting this project over from .Net without Node so I'm trying to take baby steps in the migration.

Comment: The issue here is that `controller.js` is a CommonJS/Node module, but `<script src="path/to/controller.js"></script>` knows nothing about CommonJS modules, it will just load the contents of the file into the current document without going through Node's module loader. As @dvlsg pointed out the correct way to load `controller.js` is by using `require`.